# Como associar/abrir arquivos mp3 na pasta raw?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Eu estou com probremas com musicas, sempre que adiciono alguma musica e vou executar algum código da erro, sempre que clico na musica na pasta raw aparece um texto , em tutoriais que eu vi a pessoa clica na música e toca ela vou mostrar fotos,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece porque ao copiar o arquivo para a pasta raw você associou-a como texto ou algo do género.

De qualquer forma o AndroidStudio não possui um player de música interno.

O que deve fazer é, na janela de associação, escolher a opção **"Open matching files in associated application"**
Isso irá abrir a aplicação registada no Windows para abrir arquivos com a extensão mp3.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A associação de arquivos pode ser gerida em **File -> Settings** ; **Editor/File Types**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]